# How to declare an Activiti custom FormType in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I have a Spring Boot application that is running workflows using the Activiti framework. I have got to the point where I need to create a new FormType so that I can support a field in the workflow more complex than a String/Long etc.

The article I have been following is http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2013/03/13/creating-a-new-form-property-in-activiti/

My form type is declared as

```
public class PurchaseOrderFormType extends AbstractFormType {

    private static final String FORM_TYPE = "purchaseorder";

    private String name;
    private String supplier;
    private String shippingAddress;
    private String billingAddress;
    private String issuedByAddress;

    private List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders;

    public String getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public String getShippingAddress() {
        return shippingAddress;
    }

    public void setShippingAddress(String shippingAddress) {
        this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
    }

    public String getBillingAddress() {
        return billingAddress;
    }

    public void setBillingAddress(String billingAddress) {
        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
    }

    public String getIssuedByAddress() {
        return issuedByAddress;
    }

    public void setIssuedByAddress(String issuedByAddress) {
        this.issuedByAddress = issuedByAddress;
    }

    public List<PurchaseOrder> getPurchaseOrders() {
        return purchaseOrders;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOrders(List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders) {
        this.purchaseOrders = purchaseOrders;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return FORM_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertFormValueToModelValue(String propertyValue) {
        PurchaseOrderFormType purchaseOrderFormType = new PurchaseOrderFormType();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            purchaseOrderFormType = objectMapper.readValue(propertyValue,
                PurchaseOrderFormType.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return purchaseOrderFormType;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertModelValueToFormValue(Object modelValue) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return objectMapper
                .writeValueAsString((PurchaseOrderFormType) modelValue);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The PurchaseOrder class hasn't been included here to simplify the question. It is just a POJO.

I attempted to load the form type in my spring boot application using the command line runner below, however, this appears to be too late because when I use this type in a workflow that is being loaded automatically by spring-boot the type isn't yet loaded and an exception is thrown. This exception is thrown before the initProcessEngine has been called and I've verified this in the debugger.

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner initProcessEngine(final ProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
            List<AbstractFormType> customFormTypes = new ArrayList<AbstractFormType>();
            customFormTypes.add(new PurchaseOrderFormType());
        }
    };
}
```

How can I perform the equivalent of the configuration below provided in the linked article using spring boot XML free configuration?

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" ... >
  ...
  <property name="customFormTypes">
    <list>
      ...
      <bean class="com.marc.PurchaseOrderFormType"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: How is the `ProcessEngineConfiguration` bean being created?

Comment: It is all automagical as far as I can tell. The project is based on the Spring Boot and Activiti integration so the beans are created somewhere by Spring Boot/Activiti using sensible defaults. Trouble is I no longer want the defaults and I don't have a spring config xml file anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Aciviti's Boot integration (there may be a better way to do this) but you can apply the configuration using a `BeanPostProcessor` declared as a `Bean` in your configuration class:

```java
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor activitiConfigurer() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof SpringProcessEngineConfiguration) {
                List<AbstractFormType> customFormTypes = Arrays.<AbstractFormType>asList(new PurchaseOrderFormType());
                ((SpringProcessEngineConfiguration)bean).setCustomFormTypes(customFormTypes);
            }
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }           
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had success with this using an `InitializingBean`:

```
@Bean
public InitializingBean activitiConfigurer(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration engineConfiguration) {
  return () -> engineConfiguration.setCustomFormTypes(customFormTypes);
}
```

Java 1.7 version:

```
@Bean
public InitializingBean activitiConfigurer(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration engineConfiguration) {
  return new InitializingBean() {
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      engineConfiguration.setCustomFormTypes(customFormTypes);
    }
  };
}
```